# I have a tab separated file with 4 fields. How do I get the 10 values that appeared the most in column 3?

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I have a tab separated file with 4 fields. How do I get the 10 values (along with how many times they appeared) that appeared the most in column 3?

**1. Data**

```
    .....more data above.......
    ...........................
    ...........................
    Col1-a   Col2-a  Col3-a Col4-p
    Col1-a   Col2-a  Col3-x Col4-y
    Col1-b   Col2-g  Col3-x Col4-y
    Col1-v   Col2-g  Col3-j Col4-y
    Col1-q   Col2-g  Col3-a Col4-a
    Col1-c   Col2-a  Col3-j Col4-b
    Col1-a   Col2-a  Col3-a Col4-a
```

**2. Result:**

```
    3 Col3-a
    2 Col3-j
    2 Col3-x
```

EDIT: I guess I was just looking for a command line 1-liner. If it doesn't exist, I'll totally adapt Magoo's answer and turn it into a small program.

UPDATE: I found what was I was looking for:

```
    cat file.tsv | awk '{print $3}'| sort | uniq -c | sort -bnr | head -10
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
:: remove variables starting $ or #
For %%b IN ($ #) DO FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set %%b 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q35126628.txt"
SET /a max=0
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=3delims= " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "recorded="
 FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=#=" %%c IN ('set # 2^>nul') DO IF "%%d"=="%%a" SET /a $%%c+=1&SET "recorded=y"
 IF NOT DEFINED recorded SET "#!max!=%%a"&SET /a $!max!=1
 SET /a max +=1
)

FOR /L %%x IN (%max%,-1,1) DO (FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=$=" %%a IN ('set $ 2^>nul') DO IF %%b==%%x ECHO %%b !#%%a!)
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `filename1` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q35126628.txt` containing your data for my testing.

You haven't said what your platform is, so here it is in windows-batch.

Please note that the character between `delims=` and `"` in this line

```
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=3delims= " %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
```

is a real, genuine <kbd>TAB</kbd>.